# C program printing numbers with variable precision

Tags: c, variables

Do you know how a number can be rounded up and printed with a precision that is not fixed by some natural number, but by some variable? If the user needs to enter how many decimal places to round, how to solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int r;
double var = 37.66666;
scanf("%d", &r);
printf("%.2f", var);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the format string is.... a C string.   It does not need to be a literal.  That means you could assemble a format string at runtime, eg. with sprintf().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's simple approach that would work in your case:
You just need to put * before f, and that's it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int r;
double var = 37.66666;
scanf("%d", &r);
printf("%.*f",r, var);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `*` in place of the precision, in which case you can specify an `int` as the precision.

```
printf("%.*f", r, var);
```